# Define global variable rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Right now in my view I have this:

```
@categories.each do |category|
```

And I need to define @categories in each method in controller duplicating the code.

```
def home
  @categories = Category.where(:parent_id => '').order("id").each
end

def contacts
  @categories = Category.where(:parent_id => '').order("id").each
end
```

How do I get rid of repetition?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to define class or global variables since results might be changed between queries.
I suppose add some memoization and extract duplicate into separate method:

```
def home
  categories
end

def contacts
  categories
end

def categories
  @categories ||= Category.where(:parent_id => '').order("id").each
end
```

And better to define `scope` in model:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :categories_without_parent, -> { where(:parent_id => '') }
end
```

In controller method `categories` will look like:

```
def categories
  @categories ||= Category.categories_without_parent
end
```

Comment: There is no need to define class or global variables since results might be changed between queries - what if results can't be changed between queries cause categories are something that will be added once and will stay the same for years?